# Multi Count up java script from different dates

Tags: javascript

Good day' I have searched everywhere for help on this, and unable to find answers to where i have gone wrong, or what i have done wrong, i was wondering if anyone out there is able to help me with this little bit of coding or tell me if it is not possible what im looking for is on the same html page a few count up from set dates, for example: june 16th 2012 - says #years #months #days #hours # #min #sec from this date, and then a different date and says the same from that date.. here is the code i have but cant seem to see what im doing wrong.
Thanks in advance for any help.
https://jsfiddle.net/2Lrre4ua/`cavebear`

Answer (score 0):

After looking at my script i have seen the mistake i have made. thanks anyways, the mistake i made was haveing this " window.onload=function() "